# how to determine how many arguments would be needed to fulfill fprint formatted string?

Tags: c++, c, arguments, printf

I mean strings like `"(%d%%%d) some text %s , %d%% %x %o %#x %#o \n"`. The printf family of functions somehow know how many args they would need from this string so separate argument for it is not needed. Is this functionality provided in c/c++ in terms of a separate function so I could write my own printf-like functions ? (yes I put these percents intentionally to accent how complicated it could get, so it is not simple counting of percent characters)

Comment: You walk through the string, character by character, looking for a `%` character that is followed by a legal printf format specifier and increment a counter.  When you reach the `\0` at the end of the string, your counter is the number of arguments required.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `printf` family is that it is not safe, and it *doesn't* really know or care how many format elements are there in string or in argument list.

`printf` family uses something called "variadic functions"; only one parameter is named (format string) and others are taken from the stack, without respecting their type or size - their type is deduced from format string, which makes it type-unsafe, and finds how many arguments to use by iterating over the string and finding all formatting specifiers, which makes it argument-number-unsafe. You can write variadic functions; syntax is

```
void foo(...);
```

and later you can use [those macros and types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic), although if you are using C++, you should use C++11's variadic templates instead of C variadic functions, as variadic templates are type safe - you don't loose type information anywhere, and with [universal references](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Scott-Meyers-Universal-References-in-Cpp11) (but not quite *thanks them*) they are more powerful than variadic functions.

Answer (score 1):

the printf family of functions only knows about one parameter, the first one...

It basically scans the string and each time it encounters a format specifier that it understands it pulls then next argument of that size from the argument list... this is an easily corruptible behavior.
imagine:

```
printf("%i",someInt); // fine
printf("%i",someLong); // depending on endianness and sized
                       // of those types could be the high or low 32 bits(probably)
printf("%i %i",someInt); // depending on abi could crash, read a int sized chunk
                         // of stack, or a register that would correspond to that 
                         // parameter.
```

so inherently not safe..
you should pay attention to warnings and when writing portable code do things like:

```
size_t t = 5; //can be 32 or 64 bit depending on arch.
printf("%ull",(unsigned long long)t);
```

Edit. I guess I only half answered the question...
you can define your own variadic functions, the following adds `count` number of params and returns the result.

```
int sumList(int count, ...);
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{   
    printf("the answer is: %i",sumList(4,1,2,3,4));
    return 0;
}
int sumList(int count, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, count);
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<count; i++) {
        sum += va_arg(args, int);
    }
    va_end(args);
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Note that `long` is the same size as `int` on some major compiler/systems, and not on others.  `long long` is a better example, since that's bigger than `int` on most major compiler/systems.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no standard library function for parsing printf-style format strings.  If you want to write your own string formatting function, then I strongly recommend against following the printf example.  It's inherently unsafe for the reasons mentioned in the others answers.  It also has problems with localization since word order changes in some languages.  Personally, I would write a type-safe function using templates and copying the .NET style of format strings.  (Actually, I *did* do that--it's a lot of work but also fun.)